# What is a zero point extraction system?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

In [memory alpha's page on the self-repairing minefield seen in Deep Space 9](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Self-replicating_mine), it states in the 3rd paragraph of the background information section that, "As stored material [for replicating replacement mines] begins to run out the mines have a zero-point extraction system for matter replenishment." It does not, however, explain what a zero-point extraction system is. Is there any explanation for what this is, or how it works, and has it ever been seen elsewhere in the Star Trek universe?

Comment: It is probably that this is a nod to Zero-Point Energy, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-point_energy

Comment: The main part of this question is a dupe. If you want to focus exclusively on the "has it been seen elsewhere" bit, you might want to read this; https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=1DlgE6MS49AC&pg=PT156&lpg=PT156&dq=star+trek+zero+point+energy&source=bl&ots=zhD2EaKY0v&sig=5zjSkO0kY0r8-8GI8X80hzBtVUo&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=star%20trek%20zero%20point%20energy&f=false